# Complex JSON Structure

Tags: javascript, json, database-design

I am tackling frontend development (AngularJS) and rather than pull data from the backend (which isn't complete but renders everything to JSON), I am looking to just use hardcoded JSON.

However, I am new to this and can't seem to find anything about complex JSON structure. In a basic sense, my web app has users and the content they create. So, in my mind, there will be two databases, but I'm not sure if I'm approaching it correctly.

1. Users - username, location, created content, comments, etc.

   ```
   "user": [
       {
           "userID": "12",
           "userUserName": "My Username",
           "userRealName": "My Real Name",
           "mainInterests": [
               {
                   "interest": "Guitar"
               },
               {
                   "interest": "Web Design"
               },
               {
                   "interest": "Hiking"
               }
           ],
           "userAbout": "All about me...",
           "userComments": [
               {
                   "comment": "this is a comment", "contentID" : "12"
               },
               {
                   "comment": "this is another comment", "contentID" : "123"
               }

           ],

       }
   ]
   ```
2. Created Content - title, description, username, comments, etc.

   ```
   "mainItem": [
       {
           "mainID": "1",
           "mainTitle": "Guitar Lessons",
           "mainCreatorUserName": "My Username",
           "mainCreatorRealName": "My Real Name",
           "mainTags": [
               {
                   "tag": "Intermediate"
               },
               {
                   "tag": "Acoustic"
               },
               {
                   "tag": "Guitar"
               }
           ],
           "mainAbout": "Learn guitar!",

           "mainSeries": [
               {
                   "videoFile": "file.mov",
                   "thumbnail": "url.jpg",
                   "time": "9:37",
                   "seriesNumber": "1",
                   "title": "Learn Scales"
               },
               {
                   "videoFile": "file.mov",
                   "thumbnail": "url.jpg",
                   "time": "8:12",
                   "seriesNumber": "2",
                   "title": "Learn Chords"
               }
           ],
           "userComments": [
               {
                   "comment": "this is a comment", "userID" : "12"
               },
               {
                   "comment": "this is another comment", "userID" : "123"
               }

           ]
       }
   ]
   ```

And there is more complexity than that, but I just would like to understand if I'm approaching this right. Maybe I'm even approaching this entirely incorrectly (for instance, CRUD vs. REST? Does it matter here? As I understand it, REST implies that each of the objects above are resources with their own unique URI? So would JSON rendered be impacted?). I really am not sure. But ultimately, I need to use the JSON structure properly pull data into my frontend. Assumably, whatever said structure is will be mirrored and rendered in the backend.

Edit* thank you guys for the replies. I think part of my question, where I clarify "complex", is missing. So I'd like to explain. I guess more than the JSON itself, I really mean the structure of the data. For instance, in my example, I am structuring my data to all be beneath two unique objects (user and content). Is this correct? Or should I think about my data more diverse? For instance, technically I could have a comments database (where each comment is the main object). Or is that still implied in my dataset? Perhaps my question isn't even about JSON as much as it is the data structure which will happen to get rendered in JSON. Hopefully this clarifies what I mean by complex?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: All [**JSON**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON) is valid _JavaScript_ (hence the _JS_ in _JSON_). It is a way of writing (a subset of) _Object_ literals. Every key should have a value, every value should be either another _Object_, an _Array_, a _Number_, a _String_, `true`, `false` or `null` (Hope I didn't forget any). Every item in an _Array_ in _JSON_ has to be one of these, too. So, what do you mean by "complex"?

Comment: The structure looks decent.  Some issues would occur if you tried to return ALL userComments and there were a lot of them.  You are right about REST and the URI.  The user example you posted would have a URI of something like: http://yourdomain/users/12.  The "user" is just one item however so I'd remove the '[' after `user:`

Comment: You might want to check out the [AngularJS book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028055.do) by Brad Green and Shyam Seshadri.  The chapter "Communicating with Servers" is pretty good and will give you ideas about how to implement the model/services for handling your data.

Comment: Paul, I've added a comment clarifying what I meant by complex.Chris, I will look into that book as any help with angular JS is great. Lastly, Matt, if I understand correctly then REST shouldn't change the JSON whatsoever. It would simply mean behind each object a resource URI is attached. Also what would be the reason behind the issue returning all user comments? Does it have anything to do with underlying data structure? I'd like to understand that. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're making what seems to be objects into single-item arrays (as evidenced by the opening square brackets). Other than that, it looks fine to me. Generally speaking single items (like "User") are structured as an object and multiples are arrays of objects.

As for the Angular stuff, if you want to pull direct from a JSON file as a test, take a look here:

```
var services = angular.module('app.services', [])

services.factory('User', function($http) {
    var User = function(data) { 
        return data;
    }

    User.findOne = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/test_user.json').then(function(response) { 
            return new User(response.data); 
        });
    };

    return User;
});
```

I also recomment looking into [Deployed](http://deployd.com/) for doing development without access to live data services.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions regarding pulling from JSON file. I'll also look into Deployed. What exactly do you mean by making objects single item arrays? In these instances the object mainItem or user are made just an example. I'd have multiple users or pieces of content. I'm just not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you're returning multiples, then by all means, use an array. It just seemed from your example that you were pulling back one User.